# Can Price Book be manually shared? How?

Tags: salesforce

Can Price Book be manually shared in Salesforce?

(I am not seeing the button "Sharing" on the Price Book UI)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see the "Sharing" button check the Sharing Settings for your Price Book object. It will probably be set to "Use" where doesn't really make sense to have a Sharing button.